# MFC: how to set default layout of ReBar?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

When the program is started, the default layout of ReBar is that toolbar and dialogbar side by side (top figure). How to set it such that the default layout is each bar takes one row (bottom figure)?

[image]

Comment: NVM, I've found the solution as described here if interested -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-rebarbandinfow.

Comment: Why don't you an an answer with your resolution? The link provided just documents an API ...

Answer (score 0):

Answer by myself:

When adding bands to the ReBar, use option **RBBS_BREAK**.

```
int CMainFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    ...
    if (!m_wndReBar.Create(this)
        ||  !m_wndReBar.AddBar(&m_wndToolBar, NULL, NULL, RBBS_GRIPPERALWAYS | RBBS_FIXEDBMP | RBBS_BREAK)
        ||  !m_wndReBar.AddBar(&m_wndDlgBar, NULL, NULL, RBBS_GRIPPERALWAYS | RBBS_FIXEDBMP | RBBS_BREAK))
    {
        TRACE0("Failed to create rebar\n");
        return -1;      // fail to create
    }
    ...
}
```